# Form buttons don't work

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, button, clicking

This is my first question, so I'll do my best to make it clear!

I am just starting up in WPF after several years in WinForms, and for the life of me, I can't get my buttons' events to trigger. All I currently have in the project is a border-less window with a custom rectangle for the title bar. The XAML code is:

```
 <Window
 x:Class="MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:M="clr-namespace:Metro_Test"
 Title="MainWindow"
 Height="720"
 Width="1280"
 IsTabStop="False"
 AllowsTransparency="True"
 Background="Transparent"
 BorderBrush="#FF3F3F3F"
 SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
 TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
 TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
 WindowStyle="None"
 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" AllowDrop="True" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="HandleHeaderPreviewMouseDown">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Chrome" Value="0.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Border
    x:Name="m_edgeBorder"
    Margin="14"
    Background="White">

    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect
        Opacity="0.999"
        BlurRadius="14"
        ShadowDepth="0"/>
    </Border.Effect>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">

        <Rectangle
            Height="28"
            Fill="Blue"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            AllowDrop="False"
            MouseLeftButtonDown="HandleHeaderPreviewMouseDown"/>

        <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="HandleCloseClick" MouseEnter="HandleMouseEnter" MouseLeave="HandleMouseLeave" ClickMode="Release" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="500,2,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Height="24">
            <Image Source="Images\Gray\Close.png"></Image>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="MaximiseButton" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="HandleMaximiseClick" MouseEnter="HandleMouseEnter" MouseLeave="HandleMouseLeave" ClickMode="Release" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="500,2,28,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Height="24">
            <Image Source="Images\Gray\Add.png"></Image>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="MinimiseButton" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="HandleMinimiseClick" MouseEnter="HandleMouseEnter" MouseLeave="HandleMouseLeave" ClickMode="Release" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="500,2,54,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Height="24">
            <Image Source="Images\Gray\Minus.png"></Image>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="TestBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="500,2,80,0" Width="24" Height="24">
            <Image Source="Images\Gray\Close.png"></Image>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Border>
</Window>
```

And the "Code-Behind" code is:

```
Class MainWindow

Public Sub HandleHeaderPreviewMouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        Me.DragMove()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub HandleCloseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub HandleMaximiseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    If Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Maximized Then
        Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Normal
    ElseIf Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Normal Then
        Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Maximized
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleMinimiseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Minimized
End Sub

Private Sub HandleMouseLeave(sender As Button, e As MouseEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub HandleMouseEnter(sender As Button, e As MouseEventArgs)

End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I still haven't put any commands in the MouseLeave and MouseEnter events because this problem has come up.

So far with this project, I have not once been able to get any of my buttons to work. I have tried changing the properties of the Window, Border and Grid. I have also tried removing the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown events from both the Rectangle and the Window to no avail.

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to create the event handlers manually if you don't know the exact signature. But the bigger problem here is that you handle mouse preview event (`PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="HandleHeaderPreviewMouseDown"`) for your entire window and in the event handler you call `Me.DragMove()` - which marks the event as handled, so no more mouse event handlers will be called for child controls.

You should call the `Me.DragMove()`, only if the mouse was pressed and moved ([How to get the MouseMove event when the mouse actually moves over an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550982/how-to-get-the-mousemove-event-when-the-mouse-actually-moves-over-an-element)).

Good resource about routed events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Novithchi S, I read that article and did a quick search as you suggested. I came up with this article on StackOverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592488/dragging-a-window-in-wpf-using-dragmove-method-and-click-handler-on-the-same-but 
For anyone else experience the same problem, just use the code from the above post with your upper most control, in my case "MainGrid".