# Getting Mouse Position in Status Bar using C# and Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF. In my WPF application button design have status bar. With in status bar I put one TextBlock. That Text Box wants to show current position of the mouse. If I click one control means that wants to show that controls current position. That's want to continuously change when I move cursor

```
Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(MainWindow);
Cursorposition.Text = "X:" + position.X + "Y:" + position.Y;
```

its gets only (0,0) I want change dynamically when I move cursor.

> your answer ok for mainwindow but in mainwindow I used user control means how i get?

Comment: And your question is? What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mouse.GetPosition(displayArea);` 
Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried but when I move cursor that x and y did not change

Comment: Share your code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: Mouse.GetPosition(MainWindow); Make sure MainWindow is the right instance that you are showing. If you are calling this method in MainWindow code behind just pass 'this' like 'Mouse.GetPosition(this);'

Answer (score 0):

You should update textblock text "on mouse move" event.

Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551437/2792192

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `MainWindow.xaml` in the `Window` tag

```
MouseMove="Window_MouseMove"
```

And your method should look like this:

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    Cursorposition.Text = "X:" + position.X + "Y:" + position.Y;
}
```